# Checking if string contains "HTTP://"

Tags: php, string

I am wondering why this code is not working:

```
// check to see if string contains "HTTP://" in front

if(strpos($URL, "http://")) $URL = $URL;
else $URL = "http://$URL";
```

If it does find that the string doesn't contain "HTTP://" the final string is "HTTP://HTTP://foo.foo" if it contiains "http://" in front.

Comment: If that's the actual crux, you might also want to use `stripos`, so it finds the uppercase HTTP:// too, with `if (stripos($URL,"http://")===0)`

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->startsWithIgnoreCase('http://')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L81) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 40):

Because it's returning 0 for that string, which evaluates to false. Strings are zero-indexed and as such if `http://` is found at the beginning of the string, the position is 0, not 1.

You need to compare it for strict inequality to boolean false using `!==`:

```
if(strpos($URL, "http://") !== false)
```

Comment: probably `if (substr($url, 0, 7) == 'http://')` could be faster. But this is not the place where we should apply any optimizations though ;-)

Comment: @BoltClock: did you check it? Curious to see results on ideone, for example ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: About the same, actually. My test had a typo causing it to check for an undefined var :|

Comment: @BoltClock: :-( Seems like the difference will be obvious on huge amount of data. What if url is 2kb length? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: If `strpos()` returns false, it's **much slower** (7x slower on a 2 KB string). If `strpos()` returns an integer, it's about the same speed on the same string.

Comment: @zerkms: I imagine the speed hit is on `!==` rather than `strpos()`.

Comment: Its better to use str_contains

Answer (score 15):

@BoltClock's method will work.

Alternatively, if your string is a URL you can use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), which will return the URL components in an associative array, like so:

```
print_r(parse_url("http://www.google.com.au/"));


Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.google.com.au
    [path] => /
)
```

The `scheme` is what you're after. You can use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) in conjunction with `in_array` to determine if `http` exists within the URL string.

```
$strUrl       = "http://www.google.com?query_string=10#fragment";
$arrParsedUrl = parse_url($strUrl);
if (!empty($arrParsedUrl['scheme']))
{
    // Contains http:// schema
    if ($arrParsedUrl['scheme'] === "http")
    {

    }
    // Contains https:// schema
    else if ($arrParsedUrl['scheme'] === "https")
    {

    }
}
// Don't contains http:// or https://
else
{

}
```

**Edit:**

You can use `$url["scheme"]=="http"` as @mario suggested instead of `in_array()`, this would be a better way of doing it :D

Comment: Hmm, instead of `in_array()` you could just use `($url["scheme"]=="http")`.

Comment: I just mentioned it for weirdo edge cases like `parse_url("ftp://http?http#http")`

Answer (score 8):

```
if(preg_match("@^http://@i",$String))
    $String = preg_replace("@(http://)+@i",'http://',$String);
else
    $String = 'http://'.$String;
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to remember about `https://`.
Try this:

```
private function http_check($url) {
    $return = $url;
    if ((!(substr($url, 0, 7) == 'http://')) && (!(substr($url, 0, 8) == 'https://'))) {
        $return = 'http://' . $url;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have checking if string contains “HTTP://” OR Not

Below code is perfectly working.

```
<?php 
$URL = 'http://google.com';
$weblink =   $URL; 
    if(strpos($weblink, "http://") !== false){ }
    else { $weblink = "http://".$weblink; }
 ?>
  <a class="weblink" <?php if($weblink != 'http://'){ ?> href="<?php echo $weblink; ?>"<?php } ?> target="_blank">Buy Now</a>
```

Enjoy guys...

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr_compare() [[PHP Docs]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php).

**Be careful about what the function returns. If the strings match, it returns 0.** For other return values you can check the PHP docs. There is also a parameter to check case-sensitive strings. If you specify it TRUE then it will check for upper-case letters.

So you can simply write as follows in your problem:

```
if((substr_compare($URL,"http://",0,7)) === 0) $URL = $URL;
else $URL = "http://$URL";
```

Answer (score -1):

One line solution:

```
$sURL = 'http://'.str_ireplace('http://','',$sURL);
```

Comment: You have to _check_, not _create_ URL.

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what the code of the OP does.