# Checking if a url has http:// at the beginning & inserting if not

Tags: php, http, url, if-statement, replace

I am currently editing a wordpress theme with custom field outputs.
I have successfully made all the edits and everything works as it should.
My problem is that if a url is submitted into the custom field, the echo is exactly what was in there, so if someone enters www.somesite.com the echo is just that and adds it to the end of the domain:  www.mysite.com www.somesite.com .
I want to check to see if the supplied link has the `http://` prefix at the beginning, if it has then do bothing, but if not echo out `http://` before the url.

I hope i have explained my problem as good as i can.

```
$custom = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_field', true);

<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_field', true) ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $custom ?>"> <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url');?>/lib/images/social/image.png"/></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Well, you seem to know how to use classes and templates. You should be able to figure this out with `substr` even if you can't figure out how to do this with `RegEx`, `strncmp`, or any of the many other methods....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487794/checking-if-string-contains-http

Answer (score 79, accepted):

[`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) can help...

```
$parsed = parse_url($urlStr);
if (empty($parsed['scheme'])) {
    $urlStr = 'http://' . ltrim($urlStr, '/');
}
```

Comment: lol thanks for the replies, but could somebody possibly show me an example of the required code displayed into my example?

i am a total php noob and am slowly getting familiar but still hit endless speed humps .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8591679/1110064

Figured it out and it works, i just dont understand the 'sceme' part. what is this lol

Comment: Did you maybe google `parse_url` to see what scheme is? parse_url returns an array of key/value items. See "Return Values" http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: This is a good solution, because it will not fail on case-sensitivity, or with `https://` +1

Comment: What is the ltrim() bit for?

Comment: @DaleAnderson Strips off extra / at end of a link was `http://google.com/` for example would be adjusted to `http://google.com`. Not necessary but a nice touch. I suppose it would also strip any / before the url(which would be necessary) but seems an unlikely scenario.

Comment: @Jeff This is left trim, not right trim. This part fixes the URL if you provide it like `//somesite.com/` so it does not become `https:////somesite.com/`

Answer (score 8):

You can check if `http://` is at the beginning of the string using [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos).

```
$var = 'www.somesite.com';

if(strpos($var, 'http://') !== 0) {
  return 'http://' . $var;
} else {
  return $var;
}
```

This way, if it does not have `http://` at the very beginning of the var, it will return `http://` in front of it. Otherwise it will just return the `$var` itself.

Comment: this will fail if the case does not match, or if the url starts with `https://`

Comment: In that case, one could use logic like `if(!preg_match('#^https?://#', $var)){`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo (strncasecmp('http://', $url, 7) && strncasecmp('https://', $url, 8) ? 'http://' : '') . $url;
```

Remember, that `strncmp()` returns `0`, when the first `n` letters are equal, which evaluates to `false` here. That may be a little bit confusing.

Comment: Using string functions makes it harder than necessary to deal with case and `https://`

Comment: See my edit. You can assume, that this will be the only two schemes, that may occur. Upvoted your answer anyway, because its obviously the cleaner one ;) It doesn't make sense, if I repeat it, thus I'll leave my one as an alternative, that may cover most cases, but "not that clean". Now also the case is irrelevant