# How to get a web link from a html form field

Tags: php

I am using a simple html form to for getting data from users, which the user first previews and then is posted in a Mysql database. The form is:

```
<form name="MyForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="myupload.php">
<p>Your name <input type="text" name="FormName" size="25" maxlength="50"> </p>
<p>Your email <input type="text" name="FormEmail" size="25" maxlength="50"></p>
<p> Link <input type="text" name="FormLink" size="25" maxlength="50"></p>
<p> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p> 
</form>
```

In the php page I am using the folling code:

```
$_SESSION['MyName']= $_POST['FormName'];
$_SESSION['MyEmail']= $_POST['FormEmail'];
$_SESSION['MyLink']= $_POST['FormLink'];

$myName = $_SESSION['MyName'];
$myEmail = $_SESSION['MyEmail'];    
$myLink = $_SESSION['MyLink'];

echo "Name: $myConName <br> "; 
echo "Email: $myConEmail <br>";  
echo "<a href=$myLink target=\"_blank\"> Read more</a></p>";
```

However, if the user enters `http://www.google.com/` then it works fine but if the user enters `www.google.com/` then the webpage (Google.com) cannot be shown.

Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.google.com/` is an absolute URI, `www.google.com/` is a relative URI so it doesn't point at Google's servers (unless the page displaying the link is too).

You can:

- Do nothing and make it the responsibility of the user to get the URL correct (there are lots of other errors they could make)
- Try to resolve all the URLs and reject or require the user to confirm the URL if the response isn't a 200
- Parse all the URIs and reject any that are not absolute URIs

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
if (substr($url, 0, 7) != 'http://') { 

  $myLink = "http://".$myLink;

}
```

actually it should also check if there's no "https://" – so either this could be an option:

```
if ((substr($url, 0, 7) != 'http://')&&(substr($url, 0, 8) != 'https://')) { 

  $myLink = "http://".$myLink;

}
```

or also this could be an option:

```
if (substr($url, 0, 4) != 'http') { 

  $myLink = "http://".$myLink;

}
```

…pretty close to powtac's suggestion though…

This might actually be an "almost duplicate" to this:

[Checking if string contains "HTTP://"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487794/checking-if-string-contains-http)

Comment: I think don't 100% understand what you mean? The original question was related to a user submitted URL where the "http://" was missing - or?

Comment: You solve one problem, but your solution creates a new one. With this code, if the URL entered is `https://example.com` then it gets changed to `http://https://example.com`

Answer (score 0):

After: `$myLink = $_SESSION['MyLink'];` add

```
$myLink = substr($myLink, 0, 4) == 'http' ? $myLink : 'http://'.$myLink;
```