# regex to check valid url either http or www

Tags: php, regex, url-validation

I want to check that user inserted URL is valid or not.
I have different cases to allow user to insert URL

```
1) www.test.com (valid)
2) http://test.com (valid)
3) http://www.test.com (valid)
4) www.test (not valid)
```

So this way user will able to insert `www` or `http`, If user insert only `www` then pre-append `http://` before URL.
I found many regex but they strictly check `http://`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Append before" is a contradiction in terms. The word you're looking for is "prepend."

Comment: What about URLs that don't start with www?

Comment: But www.test could be a valid domain...

Comment: @Dwev need to start with http:// or www.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_validate_url) link may help you.

```
<?php
// Variable to check
$url = "http://www.w3schools.com";

// Validate url
if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
     echo("$url is a valid URL");
} else {
     echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
?>
```

Comment: Any idea how well this works with the new TLDs, eg "subsite.site.ninja" could be a valid url (theoretically)?

Comment: yes it work with subsite.site.ninja also.

Comment: what about pre-appending http if not exist?

Comment: i think you check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487794/checking-if-string-contains-http]

Comment: @NikunjChotaliya if i type www.test.com it return fail.

Comment: @Sanket Sorthiya as per above comment you need to check url contains http:// or not then prepend it in url and use above php function.

Answer (score 0):

I think in point 3. you have an misstake. You have written "wwww"

apart from this, correct regex pattern could be the following:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,3}$
```

Comment: There are also domains like `example.info`; `example.name`; `example.berlin` and so on which aren't considered with this regex.

Comment: so it will check if http exist or not if not exist then pre-append it. so how it will work?

Comment: question mark sets the previous sign or group optional, it means "http://" or "https://" can exists or not, but if exists, it cannot be different. With group `(www\.)` this same, becouse there is a question mark after it. `^` at start means that in string anything cannot be befor "http"